# git master cannot merge branch

Tags: git, branch

I'm new to git and I have created a branch (b1) from master

but the issue is, in the b1 branch has the codes I need and I need to merge those codes to master.but when i checkout to the master and try to merge the the b1 branch in to the master it says already updated.but that is not true. any suggestion

Comment: I don't follow the problem.  As a wild guess, I might speculate that you did not commit your work in the `b1` branch.  Please update your question clearly showing the steps you took.

Comment: From what I understand you probably try to merge the master to the branch and the result is that it is already update it.

Comment: hi all ,Question updated

Comment: You must post the commands you execute along with their output. You must be doing something wrong but since you we're only *told* what you do, we can only assume everything is true, but clearly it isn't. So post the commands you execute.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are on master:

```
git branch
```

=> * should be next to master

if not:

```
git checkout master
```

Check if everything in master is commited:

```
git status
```

If not everything is commited:
 - git add .
 - git commit -m 'added missing files'
 - optional: git push

Delete old branch to be clean:

```
git branch -d b1
```

Make a new branch:

```
git branch b1
```

Switch to new branch:

```
git checkout b1
```

Now everything should be as desired ;-)

Comment: are you saying to delete the branch and create a branch with the same name?

Comment: Basically: Yes. Just follow the sequence I proposed and it should just work.

Comment: Did that work for you? Please accept the answer, if it did ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The way you should work is this :

1. `git checkout -b 'yourBranch'`
2. `make changes to your branch`
3. `git add . (to add your changes)`
4. `git commit -m "Your message on commit"`
5. `git push origin 'yourBranch' (if there is a remote repo)`
6. `git checkout master (to return on the master repo)`
7. `git merge 'yourBranch'`

Also, you can have a nice look here [git-basic](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)